# Python Multiple Inheritance super method call

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I was reading [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-python/) article but I cannot understand the following example:

```
class Class1: 
    def m(self): 
      print("In Class1") 
      print("here1")
  
class Class2(Class1): 
    def m(self): 
        print("In Class2") 
        super().m() 
        print("here2")
  
class Class3(Class1): 
    def m(self): 
        print("In Class3") 
        super().m() 
        print("here3")
  
class Class4(Class2, Class3): 
    def m(self): 
        print("In Class4")    
        super().m() 
       
obj = Class4() 
obj.m()
```

The result is:

```
In Class4
In Class2
In Class3
In Class1
here1
here3
here2
```

Why is the result printed in that order? I expected the result to be:

```
In Class4
In Class2
In Class1
here1
here2
In Class3
In Class1
here1
here3
```

Why is `super().m()` discarded when we enter `Class2`? it only runs when we finish printing "In Class3".

Thanks

Comment: Given the result you see, you should be able to work out for yourself the order in which the program runs.

Comment: @quamrana Why is the order like that? shouldn't the program run the super class method whenever it reaches super().m()? it only happens once and at the end of the program

Comment: The linked article does not go into much detail, but this behavior is controlled through Python's "Method Resolution Order" (MRO) rules.  [This](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/python/mro.aspx) link has some more in-depth examples and explanations.  In essence, `super()` does *not* mean "call this method from the parent class," but rather: "call this method from the next class in MRO."

Comment: @0x5453 That makes perfect sense. I didn't know it works like that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of Python's method resolution order.
You can view the MRO of your classes by calling `Class4.mro()` for example.
You will see that `Class3` comes before `Class1`. This is because Python's MRO (https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) uses the C3 Linearization algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

Quoting Guido van Rossum (from wikipedia):

> Basically, the idea behind C3 is that if you write down all of the ordering rules imposed by inheritance relationships in a complex class hierarchy, the algorithm will determine a monotonic ordering of the classes that satisfies all of them. If such an ordering can not be determined, the algorithm will fail.

You can read into the algorithm, but a simplistic view I like to hold about the alogirthm is this:
*It's basically a DFS from left to right, but a subclass will always be earlier than it's superclass.*

Note: this is a simplistic view of the rule, and it not covers the algorithm nor the failed cases, but in most cases it's a good way to remember the MRO basics.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing the the order of all the class locations first because you are calling that super class

```
def m(self): 
    print("In Class3") 
    super().m() 
    print("here3")
```

See you are calling super().m() which will cause the parent classes self function to run which holds the print("In Classn") statement in that fucntion, which will then call the next super().m() causing another self function to be ran. You need to print the here before hand.

Comment: My question is why we don't run Class1 m method when we call super().m() from Class2? according to  the result, we run Class1 m method only once and after in Class2 and in Class 3 are printed